# given json response how to binding in list flutter using dio?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

{
"success": true,
"data": [
{
"id": 11,
"order_ref_no": "OA-1624432086",
"customer_id": 1,
"customer_address_id": 1,
"order_date": "2021-06-23",
"delivery_date": "2021-06-27",
"delivery_time_from": "12:00:00",
"delivery_time_to": "14:00:00",
"sub_total": 679,
"delivery_charges": 22,
"order_total": 701,
"order_status": "completed",
"customer": {
"id": 1,
"photo": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=17nPK4ChZG1Pv7hkYI0MN2ZYsjj646yI7&export=media",
"first_name": "vishal",
"last_name": "sharma",
"email": "vishal@gmail.com",
"mobile": "+91 1111111111",
"dob": "2021-06-17",
"mobile_verified": "true",
"fcm_token": null,
"latitude": null,
"longitude": null,
"status": "active",
"created_at": "2021-06-17 05:35:51",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 10:28:00"
},
"customer_address": {
"id": 1,
"customer_id": 1,
"address_type": "office",
"receiver_name": "megha",
"receiver_contact_number": "9632589632",
"state_id": 1,
"area": "nikol",
"pincode": 382350,
"house_no": "c-122",
"city_id": 2,
"address_1": "bhakti circle",
"address_2": "Ahmedabad,gujarat,india",
"latitude": "23.1218578",
"longitude": "72.545334",
"created_at": "2021-06-17 10:07:36",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 07:06:04",
"deleted_at": null
},
"order_invoice": [
{
"id": 10,
"order_id": 11,
"vendor_id": 8,
"delivery_boy_id": 1,
"invoice_ref_no": "INV-16244320863",
"total": 199,
"admin_commission": 0,
"invoice_total": 199,
"status": "delivered",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 13:17:42",
"vendor_data": {
"id": 8,
"vendor_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1sLdbAUjb9TbVUX6yxdZ6qbMi9EDUbjkf&export=media",
"vendor_name": "Veggy Shop",
"employee_name": "Srikant",
"dob": "1980-06-17",
"admin_share": "2",
"mobile": "+91 9292929292",
"email": "sri@gmail.com",
"city_id": 1,
"delivery_range": "2",
"is_best_seller": 1,
"is_trending": 1,
"latitude": "19.6641°",
"longitude": "78.5320°",
"fcm_token": null,
"vendor_address": "Near Head Street",
"start_time": null,
"end_time": null,
"time_interval": null,
"created_at": "2021-06-17 12:29:48",
"updated_at": "2021-06-17 12:29:48",
"vendor_status": "online",
"status": "active",
"mobile_verified": "false"
},
"order_invoice_items": [
{
"id": 25,
"invoice_id": 10,
"vendor_id": 8,
"product_id": 6,
"product_name": "Fresh Orange",
"product_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1qgYHU1Bdqt4o8KZsY4lhyJl5Wsn_Bcxp&export=media",
"unit": "Kg",
"weight": "1",
"qty": 1,
"mrp": 299,
"price": 199,
"total_price": 199,
"vendor_admin_commission": 0,
"item_status": "pending",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06"
}
]
},
{
"id": 11,
"order_id": 11,
"vendor_id": 1,
"delivery_boy_id": 1,
"invoice_ref_no": "INV-16244320866",
"total": 360,
"admin_commission": 0,
"invoice_total": 360,
"status": "delivered",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 13:17:42",
"vendor_data": {
"id": 1,
"vendor_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Zwskric14eE6vfDVINALWEiczP7Y0SNo&export=media",
"vendor_name": "Shiv Shakti Dairy",
"employee_name": "Shashikant Gupta",
"dob": "1999-06-01",
"admin_share": "5",
"mobile": "+91 1234567890",
"email": "shiv@yahoo.com",
"city_id": 5,
"delivery_range": "5",
"is_best_seller": 1,
"is_trending": 1,
"latitude": "23.0550°",
"longitude": "72.5493°",
"fcm_token": null,
"vendor_address": "Near Dream lack",
"start_time": null,
"end_time": null,
"time_interval": null,
"created_at": "2021-06-17 06:58:37",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 10:31:47",
"vendor_status": "online",
"status": "active",
"mobile_verified": "false"
},
"order_invoice_items": [
{
"id": 26,
"invoice_id": 11,
"vendor_id": 1,
"product_id": 1,
"product_name": "Amul Milk",
"product_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1O61-FmFD0pgqSKpgjRdi4X6wEMtaQF7l&export=media",
"unit": "Kg",
"weight": "1",
"qty": 2,
"mrp": 200,
"price": 180,
"total_price": 360,
"vendor_admin_commission": 0,
"item_status": "pending",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06"
}
]
},
{
"id": 12,
"order_id": 11,
"vendor_id": 7,
"delivery_boy_id": 1,
"invoice_ref_no": "INV-16244320869",
"total": 480,
"admin_commission": 0,
"invoice_total": 480,
"status": "delivered",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 13:17:42",
"vendor_data": {
"id": 7,
"vendor_image": null,
"vendor_name": "vikas sharma",
"employee_name": "vikas",
"dob": "1996-08-20",
"admin_share": "2",
"mobile": "+91 9772718131",
"email": "vks7860@gmail.com",
"city_id": 9,
"delivery_range": "50",
"is_best_seller": 0,
"is_trending": 0,
"latitude": "27.903875000000003",
"longitude": "74.925035",
"fcm_token": null,
"vendor_address": "sikar",
"start_time": null,
"end_time": null,
"time_interval": null,
"created_at": "2021-06-17 10:26:56",
"updated_at": "2021-06-24 12:56:23",
"vendor_status": "online",
"status": "active",
"mobile_verified": "true"
},
"order_invoice_items": [
{
"id": 27,
"invoice_id": 12,
"vendor_id": 1,
"product_id": 1,
"product_name": "Amul Milk",
"product_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1O61-FmFD0pgqSKpgjRdi4X6wEMtaQF7l&export=media",
"unit": "Kg",
"weight": "1",
"qty": 2,
"mrp": 200,
"price": 180,
"total_price": 360,
"vendor_admin_commission": 0,
"item_status": "pending",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06"
},
{
"id": 28,
"invoice_id": 12,
"vendor_id": 7,
"product_id": 9,
"product_name": "Chocolate Cack",
"product_image": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1yeuAQaiRH9656oUzsaR7-Bu8147RK3Q3&export=media",
"unit": "Litres",
"weight": "1.25",
"qty": 2,
"mrp": 75,
"price": 60,
"total_price": 120,
"vendor_admin_commission": 0,
"item_status": "pending",
"created_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 07:08:06"
}
]
}
],
"order_payment": {
"id": 25,
"order_id": 11,
"payment_mode": "Cash on delivery",
"transaction_id": "paisa lai lidha che",
"comment": "vshs",
"amount": 701,
"document": null,
"created_at": "2021-06-23 11:21:59",
"updated_at": "2021-06-23 11:21:59"
},
"status": "delivered"
}
],
"message": "Order detail found successfully!!"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Parth,
Your question is not clear but As I understand you are trying to get "data" field into list. Only call following ;

```
List armut = yourjsonname["data"];
```

Please when you attempt to ask question, give information about it next time.

Comment: i need a data  inside to Invoice List.

Comment: What do you mean by Invoice List? If you mean "order_invoice" field go for yourjsonname["data"][0]["order_invoice"];